# magento cms pages and checking if customer logged in

Tags: magento

I have a CMS page that has a download link on it.  Here is what I need to happen:

1. keep the download link if the user is logged in.
2. if the user isn't logged in, change the behavior of the link so it is a link to register.

I see that there is layout update xml i can use `<customer_logged_in>` and potentially change that link based on that.  How can I use that layout update xml in this cms page so that the link is different?

Or is there a better approach that I could try?

Comment: otherwise my only other idea is to specify the download link inside of the cms content as a block with a template.  inside of the template I do my check and then when it renders the html it'll show the correct link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better approach is to go with your custom block creation. Here is how you can achieve what you want.

1) Create a CMS page and in content section include your custom block

**For Ex:**

```
{{block type="core/template" name="download_page" template="YourTemplateFolder/TemplateFileName.phtml"}}
```

2) Check if customer is logged in or not.

**For Ex:**

```
 <?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?> //If user is logged in
 <?php $downloadUrl = 'Your Download URL'; ?> //generate your download URL

    <div>
    <?php echo $downloadUrl; ?> // Allow user to download 
    </div>

    <?php else: ?>//If user is NOT logged in
    <?php $registerUrl = 'Your Register URL'; ?> //generate your register URL

    <div>
    <?php echo $registerUrl; ?> // Ask user to Register
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the comment on this.  this is the route i ended up going.  glad to see some validation on the route i went.

Comment: <?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?> //If user is NOT logged in. :)